# Selective use of "text" variable in google fonts calls

Tags: css, url, text, fonts

I'm using three Google fonts in a project, where the two first are for headings and regular text, and the third is just for the menu. So, in the menu, I only use a set of letters, all uppercase. When I import the Google fonts "css" I can reduce the size of the third font by 85% if I only call the letters I need, using the "text" variable in the URL:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Happy+Monkey&text=HOMECONTACT);
```

This is great, but when I add the other fonts to this URL (in order to save calls), the "text" variable affects all the fonts in the URL. So, the solution is to consume one more call and ask for the fonts separately, like this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Happy+Monkey&text=HOMECONTACT);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?Marcellus+SC|Open+Sans+Condensed:300);
```

Now, what I'd like to do, is to retrieve all the fonts in one call, but only a set of characters for one specific font. In other words, combine the previous calls in one. Reading the Google fonts API, I assume it's not possible, but still, I'm asking if anyone knows of a solution for this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do that yet. Maybe because the optimized font requests are still in beta.

What I recommend is to use requests in the `<head>` instead of using inside CSS with `@import`. From a page speed standpoint, @import from a CSS file should almost never be used, as it can prevent stylesheets from being downloaded concurrently. If both stylesheets are referenced in `<link>` elements in the main HTML page, both can be downloaded at the same time.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Happy+Monkey&text=HOMECONTACT">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?Marcellus+SC|Open+Sans+Condensed:300">
```

Even with one more request, the page will load faster than with `@import`.

Answer (score 0):

While we're currently limited to multiple requests, a service worker can cache both responses so that they're instantaneously resolved on subsequent page loads.

Answer (score -1):

As of right now (April 2020) ,
You can do this.
https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2#optimizing_your_font_requests

Comment: It doesn't seem like it - true, there is possibility to specify "text" query param, but setting it affect all of the loaded font families.
The question asked is about loading multiple font families & specifying different text ranges for them.